# Windows SDK environment and powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

The windows v7.1 SDK has a `SetEnv.Cmd` script in its binary folder to correctly setup its environment. The problem is this script obviously only works with `cmd.exe` and I can't find an equivalent for powershell anywhere.

So am I forced to use cmd.exe or is there a way to use powershell (apart from manually rewriting the SetEnv.Cmd script - if even that would work?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone wrote a ps1 script that parses out the SDK's setenv so you can avoid the extra processes:

http://www.tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/The-last-vsvars32ps1-Ill-ever-need.aspx

Comment: Accepted as the answer because it seems to work fine (although it sets some variables that I don't think should actually be set and needs a tweak to ignore null variables) and it's more elegant (or overengineered ;)) than the other solution.

Comment: And the link is dead

Comment: @mlt install-module pscx; Import-VisualStudioVars -VisualStudioVersion 2017

Answer (score 2):

You can launch an instance of CMD.EXE, run SetEnv.cmd, and then launch PowerShell from within the CMD window.  The PowerShell instance that opens up will import the environment variables from the CMD instance that spawned it.

It's ugly, but it works.

I wrote a batch script to do it for me, and just created a shortcut to it on my desktop.  Here's an example:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Path\To\SetEnv.cmd" param1 param2 param3
powershell.exe -noexit
```

Comment: In this case "works as expected" is all I care for. Powershell is oh so much nicer than cmd.